# Retrieve values from 1 million plus csv files using VBScript

Tags: vba, csv

I need to copy values from multiple files(say One million csv files) and paste it into Master.

Attached is the code snippet:-

```
Public Sub GetDataFromClosedBook()
Dim Filename As String
Dim wkb As Workbook

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Meter-1").Visible = True
Sheets("Meter-1").Select

mydata = "G:\BIS Dashboard(Finalised-13012016)\Files_Oct-21\"
Filename = Dir(mydata & "\AC PANEL-2_22_**************.csv", vbNormal)

Do Until Filename = ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=mydata & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheets(1).Range("C8, E8").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Meter-  1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop

Sheets("Meter-1").Select
Sheets("Meter-1").Visible = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Above code runs perfectly and retrieve values if csv files are less(say 1000 csv files) but how ever i want to retrieve values from all the files.

Code runs for a while and does not respond and finally excel get crashes after hour or so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Trying to do this through automation is asking for trouble and will be a too greater overhead.

Comment: It loops all worksheets, but only uses sheet 1, is there only 1 sheet, no need for loop, if there is more than one sheet, you're only using sheets(1), nothing uses Sheet.  You could also look at ADO, using https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/   and   http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Excel/InsertarowtoaworksheetbyusingtheSQLstatement.htm   not saying this will definitely fix, but worth a try....

Comment: how many rows each *.cvs need to be copied? and how many *.cvs file are there exactly?

Comment: There is only 1 sheet in each csv file. I wanted to copy only two cell values from each workbook which consists of one worksheet.@ Susilo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, there is only one sheet in csv file and I will make changes as per your suggestion.@Nathan_Sav

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this makes no sense:

```
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheets(1).Range("C8, E8").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Meter-  1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next Sheet
```

Your goal seems to loop on all the sheets of the current book, but by saying `Sheets(1).` it always take the first sheet and so you'll end up with duplicates values. Do `Sheet.` instead.

Then, if you have really one million files to process, you should radically change your approach to limit the memory used at all time.

Some tips:

1. dont host your script in Excel. It seems that you do this from Excel VBA right now. Move this in standalone VBscript. You'll have to rewrite the code a litlle bit to use an Excel object instead of `Application.`, like this `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
2. dont even try to write your results in an Excel file, you'll get out of memory at some point. Write it in a simple text file instead, using *File System Object* aka **FSO**.
   You'll import the results back in Excel from the text file afterwards.

   3. inside your loop, you should make sure that the memory garbage is cleaned at all times. You should instantiate a workbook object and kill it when your copy is done. First loop step should be something like `Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(mydata & Filename)` and when your copy stuff is done, prior to loop to the next one, do a `Set objWorkbook = Nothing`

All this wont guarantee that you'll achieve what you want but will increase a lot your chances

I am in the train on my phone, so sorry but I cant give more details and format better.

good luck

Comment: Sorry, there is a  small edit in the code, I am reposting the code again.@Thomas G

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, I will work on it and i will post the results very soon@Thomas G

Answer (score 0):

```
Do Until Filename = ""
On Error Resume Next
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(mydata & Filename)
wkb.Sheets.Range("C8, E8").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Meter-1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
wkb.Close False
Filename = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

1,000,000?  holy crap!  i'm not sure Excel or VBA or anything of that nature will handle the task.  can you use SQL server for this job?  there must be a pattern in the names of the files...i certainly hope so...  try SQL server express, which you can get for free using the link below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

then, loop through the CSV files, using whatever pattern you can.  in the script below, i'm changing the date, one day at a time.  this is just an example.  i'm sure you don't have 1,000,000 dates, unless you are measuring something from when the dinosaurs were walking around.  just change the script to suit your needs.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=10000)
BEGIN

PRINT @intFlag


declare @fullpath1 varchar(1000)
select @fullpath1 = '''\\FTP\your_path' + convert(varchar, getdate()- @intFlag , 112) + '_your_file.txt'''
declare @cmd1 nvarchar(1000)
select @cmd1 = 'bulk insert [dbo].[your_table] from ' + @fullpath1 + ' with (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR=''0x0a'')'
exec (@cmd1)


SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1

END
GO
```